# XFCC header added by Istio does not contain the client certificate

Tags: istio, client-certificates, mtls

I'm trying to get the istio ingress-gateway to forward the client certificate to my service for mTLS. I've tried the following configuration from the [page](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/network-topologies/#configuring-x-forwarded-client-cert-headers).

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  meshConfig:
    defaultConfig:
      gatewayTopology:
        forwardClientCertDetails: ALWAYS_FORWARD_ONLY
```

If I test this with httpbin service by sending a request with client cert as follows:

```
curl -v https://<my-FQDN>/headers --cacert CAcert.pem --cert client.pem --key client.key.pem
```

Then in the response I see the XFCC header with only ingress-gateway certificate. I don't see the client certificate in the XFCC header.

```
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Length": "0",
    "Host": "<my-FQDN>",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.60.0",
    "X-B3-Parentspanid": "535ccd58be2707d1",
    "X-B3-Sampled": "0",
    "X-B3-Spanid": "859fe154b4b4f732",
    "X-B3-Traceid": "c3a2d51fe8843dfa535ccd58be2707d1",
    "X-Custom-Client-Ip": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    "X-Envoy-Attempt-Count": "1",
    "X-Envoy-External-Address": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    "X-Forwarded-Client-Cert": "By=spiffe://cluster.local/ns/default/sa/httpbin;Hash=be931817624826a918707c148730ee0338b6aaa5e21a27c78b1abeafead6fd04;Subject=\"CN=istio-ingressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local,C=US,OU=MGMT,O=XXXXX\";URI=spiffe://cluster.local/ns/istio-system/sa/istio-ingressgateway-service-account"
  }
```

How do I get the client certificate added in the XFCC header?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ALWAYS_FORWARD_ONLY means an existing XFCC header will be forwarded. Did you try APPEND_FORWARD ?

Comment: I did try the other options like APPEND_FORWARD, SANITIZE. I'm getting the same result as shown above for all of these values.

Answer (score 0):

following configuration works for me

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    proxy.istio.io/config: '{"gatewayTopology" :{"forwardClientCertDetails":"SANITIZE_SET"}}'
    sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
  labels:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
  name: istio-ingressgateway-68b958bfc6-bmx7p
  namespace: istio-system
```

request header is as follows:

```
                "headers":{
                    ":authority":"127.0.0.1:8443",
                    ":method":"GET",
                    ":path":"/",
                    ":scheme":"https",
                    "accept":"*/*",
                    "user-agent":"curl/7.79.1",
                    "x-forwarded-client-cert":"Hash=ac0112fdcdc77852b3e13594a1b4a4969869c2fa25073f97e8b4ab45a1941ee8;Cert=\"-----BEGIN%20CERTIFICATE-----%0AMIIDEDCCAfigAwIBAgIIRCLTvOmPyXowDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwPjEnMBIGA1UE%0AChMLQWxpYmFiYS5JbmMwEQYDVQQKEwpBbGlwYXkuSW5jMRMwEQYDVQQDEwpLdWJl%0Acm5ldGVzMB4XDTIwMDQwMTA3MzgzNloXDTMwMDMzMDA3Mzg0MFowKTEXMBUGA1UE%2BelmzcxQ6%0AE71Q2xiMH%2BJLAbOdixuI2s4zQQRLRV36Q%2BYPguMKl7mKIZGbE4oBqRM9yWWsWPvF%0AKRSIJIw8JWGhxAHedfzIjwAcTylv8u3KR%2BKoQKYtxrM07s8r7OnnvVJ0VWtwtAKM%0AxBpWc0C%2BPfL%2B7vYUoWo3Al%2BRZI6iDDY53ppRBLkvzSDZ7hU153bxqVG3XQF177MM%0AkGhZKX26GNYJe5a6h108p8A5xIo%3D%0A-----END%20CERTIFICATE-----%0A\";Subject=\"CN=admin,O=system:masters\";URI=",
                    "x-forwarded-proto":"https",
                    "x-request-id":"625a6941-1ff0-438f-bdde-d70f1512791c"
                },
```